# manipulate the HEX value of a variable in COBOL

Tags: cobol

Using a constant does work: `MOVE X "41" TO HEXSTRING-WRK.` 
Value of HEXSTRING-WRK = 'A

But the hex-value "41" should be variable, how can this be realized with `MOVE`?
My attempts without success:

```
01 TEST-VAR PIC X(28) VALUE "41".
01 HEXSTRING-WRK PIC X(28).  
01 HEXSTRING-WRK2 PIC X(30).  


STRING '"X"' DELIMITED BY SIZE     
               TEST-VAR DELIMITED BY SIZE  
 INTO HEXSTRING-WRK2                                   
END STRING.                                            
                                                                                
MOVE HEXSTRING-WRK2 TO HEXSTRING-WRK.
```

Hex value of HEXSTRING -> 2258223431

IBM COBOL on the AS400

Comment: What compiler / environment do you use? IBM COBOL on AS400?

Comment: The current approach cannot work as you want the hex value, and `x'1234'` is the way you can write down a constant in hexadecimal format.
A common "trick" to achieve something like you've outlined is redefine (a single position `X`) as computational and move the appropriate numeric value to it.

Most COBOL systems have extensions like `CALL`ables but this depends on the system you use (you may edit this information into your question).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you convert from Hex to Ascii using different inputs in COBOL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63526832/how-do-you-convert-from-hex-to-ascii-using-different-inputs-in-cobol)

Comment: IBM COBOL on the AS400. Maybe you can show me the trick.